Why can't my pycharm code use bm3d library in my MacBookpro m3
each time I run my code ,it will catch error about the bm3d ,how can I solve it?
def run_bm3d(image_noisy, sigma):
    
    denoised_img = np.zeros_like(image_noisy)
    
  
    for channel in range(image_noisy.shape[2]):
        
        channel_data = image_noisy[:, :, channel]
        
        
        denoised_channel = bm3d(channel_data, sigma)
        
       
        denoised_img[:, :, channel] = denoised_channel
    
    return denoised_img

the error says that:
OSError: dlopen(/Users/wangzhizhou/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bm4d/libbm4d_mac.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/wangzhizhou/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bm4d/libbm4d_mac.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/wangzhizhou/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bm4d/libbm4d_mac.so' (no such file), '/Users/wangzhizhou/opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bm4d/libbm4d_mac.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))


I am not sure it can be an error about my system structure or other aspect?
how can I can use the bm3d correctly?

What output do you get when running python3 -c 'import platform; print(platform.platform())'? This thread may be helpful. When setting up your conda environment you can specify whether they should use Apple ARM or Intel-x64.

it shows that 'macOS-14.3.1-arm64-arm-64bit'

so how to specify the environment with the apple arm or x64

when I used my anaconda to create a environment, it only ask me to choose a version of python

This thread has a few answers on how to do so.

so how can I solve this problem , I am newcomer to the conda environment
